# IRC Client Sending Messages Improperly, C++

Tags: c++, sockets, irc

The problem occurs when sending messages. They segment into individual messages where spaces are. The messages are composed using `sprintf(message, "PRIVMSG %s :%s\n", irc_chan, buffer);` The error will appear as follows(Individual messages are contained in `""`s). I will enter a message `"Hi there"`. It will output `"Hi"` `"there"`. buffer is a `char[1024]`. Any ideas please let me know.

The following is the part of the code that sends the message, the class I've used for the socket is of no concern to you, I can receive messages and connect FINE.

```
scanf("%s", buffer);
sprintf(message, "PRIVMSG %s :%s", irc_chan, buffer);
send(IRCSocket.iSocket, message, strlen(message), 0);
```

EDIT: I resolved this with help from Computer Guru. I was using scanf(), I should have been using cin.getline(); Thanks for the help, MUCH appreciated.

Comment: Stdin, scanf("%s", buffer); scanf("%s", &buffer); makes no difference.

Comment: What is  "it" and "they" in this context ?

Comment: They are the messages I send. It refers to the actual program and other IRC clients. Basically the outputted message.

Comment: This depends on how you "enter" your messages too. Show us your code. There are too many ways to screw this up.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `scanf()` over `std::cin.getline()`? getline will capture everything up until the break character.

Answer (score 3):

`%s` does not include spaces. Each word will be captured individually.

Comment: Oh... thank you I much appreciate this. I'm embarrassed that I didn't know that. Thank you for alerting me to this. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: No problem. You can loop over fget to get a single character at a time until you reach the end, or else use line-by-line functions such as getline().

Answer (score 0):

Here's from [`scanf(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/scanf.3.html) manual page:

> `s     Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer
>            must be a pointer to char, and the array must be large enough to
>            accept all the sequence and the terminating NUL character.  The
>            input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width,
>            whichever occurs first.`

It's also way too easy to overrun the end of the buffer that way. Use [`fgets(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fgets.3.html) instead. In C++ (since that's your tag) you can use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).